# Mark global inbox items as read after viewing

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ says I've got replies, but I've already viewed those.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67987/the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-says-ive-got-replies-but-ive-a)

I often read comments before noticing the unread count in the global inbox. Then I click on the stackexchange logo to see what's new and find the "unread comments" are those I've already read.

The best way IMHO to fix this is to mark items as read once you've viewed the page on which the comment was written. The obvious problem here is that viewing the page does not imply I read the comment. But I find with myself this is far more often the case then not. However, if you don't agree it should at the very least be marked as read after I make a comment in reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I could have sworn there was already a declined [feature-request] for this... but I can't find it.

Anyway, this is a such a minor issue (and you yourself noted that we can't actually detect when someone has read something) that I have no intention of ever addressing it.  I would rather the "new" notices in the inbox be reliable (if occasionally annoying) than consistently pseudo-buggy, basically.

Comment: Found it for you.