# The Inbox still shows 1 even though I am on the page it is referring to

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ says I've got replies, but I've already viewed those.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67987/the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-says-ive-got-replies-but-ive-a)

Here is the example and repro.

1. I ask a question.
2. Go home, meanwhile someone has answered the question, come back the next day, refresh the page
3. The Inbox still shows 1 even though I am looking at the page it is referring to.

[image]

The [question](https://superuser.com/questions/273023/remotely-accessing-a-mac-from-windows-in-a-sane-manner) in question.

Comment: If you view every page on the entire network, you will still have a **1** there until you open your inbox.  It means your inbox hasn't been viewed.  I don't view this as a bug.