# Fixing the notification menu

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ says I've got replies, but I've already viewed those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67987/the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-says-ive-got-replies-but-ive)

I was wondering, sometimes, I am on a question, but I still get a notification, on top where the logo is,

I find it annoying, because I would have to click it, to remove the notification thingy, or I think it could be something else.

I was thinking, why not get rid of the notifications that lead to the page you already are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some questions, I will provide both a comment on the question and an answer. It is possible that I could be talking to someone in the comments on my answer, and someone would comment on the question and even mention my name. Without a different notification, I would not know about that. I think it's fine the way it is.

If you are really annoyed by it, you could always cook up a GreaseMonkey script that removes notifications if they are about the page you are on, but it barely takes a second to remove it.