# Dismiss inbox item when I've already seen it another way

Tags: discussion, top-bar, global-inbox

It looks obvious that if I've already seen an item in inbox without opening the inbox proper, the notification should be dismissed since it's of no use anymore.
(if it's not obvious to you, please specify)

The main question is: *what reliable technical ways to determine that I have read the corresponding item you can think of?*

As of this writing, I've come with these:

- Clicked on the link "load N more comments" if the item is among them
- Clicked on "the post has been edited" for an edit notification

Comment: [c874112](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269767/dismiss-inbox-item-when-ive-already-seen-it-another-way#comment874112_269768). This, however, means that I can drop the [tag:feature-request] tag.

Comment: Is it really a dupe? That is a bug report, but this is a discussion...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ agree, voted to reopen

Comment: @ShadowWizard lol - 'vote' is questionable ;P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ lol, didn't even notice I used the hammer!

Answer (score 3):

Although this seems to be a nice feature, but I'm just adding here, in the discussion, that Kevin Montrose has [previously said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67996/260841) that the inbox will **never** care about when you last viewed the actual items (emphasis mine):

> The number is the number of items added to the inbox since you last viewed the inbox, **it does not (and will never) care about when you last viewed any of the items referred to by its contents.**

---

Let's hope we can convince SE otherwise! :)

Comment: My concern is not whether this is currently acceptable to the devs. Their position is most probably to resist overcomplicating things (and I cannot agree more). Thus the puspose of the current topic is to determine how much (or rather, how little) (over)complication this can possibly be.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I understand, I'm just pointing this out so everybody who sees this knows what has happened in the past! :)